# Output of type(object) not returned in Assert message (Databricks Python)

Tags: python, types, databricks, assertion, f-string

When applying the Python function type() to a single object, the type of the object is returned.

```
num = 5
type(num) 

Out[1]: int
```

When embedding this output into a string and printing the result, this seems to behave as expected.

```
num = 5
print(f"type of {num} is {type(num)}")

type of 5 is <class 'int'>
```

However, when using this exact message as an assertion error message, the type disappears from the message output.

```
num = 5
assert isinstance(num,str), f"type of {num} is {type(num)}"

AssertionError: type of 5 is
```

I am running the code through a notebook on a **Databricks cluster**, which is displayed in a web browser.
The expected output would be: `AssertionError: type of 5 is <class 'int'>`.

What is the reason for this and how can it be avoided?

Edit: As mentioned by several commenters, the code works just fine running outside of the databricks environment. I have successfully verified this too using Python 3.10.6.

Comment: Works fine for me in Python 3.8.6 IDLE.

Comment: I cannot replicate this.  Is this specific to the DataBricks tag?

Comment: @MarkRansom, thanks for the reply. Perhaps this is related to me running the code on a databricks instance? Do you have any idea what could possibly have influence on this?

Comment: @James, thanks for the reply. Given Mark's answer as well, I'm indeed assuming it must be related to the databricks instance in which the Python code is being executed. Do you have any idea what could possibly be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: nothing comes to mind offhand.  You could try breaking apart the pieces.  `t=type(num)`, then `assert isinstance(num,str), f"type of {num} is {t}"`, to see if the f-string evaluation within the assert if not working

Comment: @James, thanks for the suggestion. Didn't work unfortunately. Open for any suggestions :)

Comment: I have no idea.  You may want to raise an issue on the DataBricks github: https://github.com/databricks

Comment: try adding the `!r`: `assert isinstance(num,str), f"type of {num} is {type(num)!r}"`

Comment: @James no luck either when using `!r` unfortunately.

Comment: Is this being displayed in a browser? If so, the `<` is probably being interpreted as the beginning of an HTML tag. Try `f"type of {num} is {type(num)}".replace("<", "&lt;")`

Comment: What does `running the code on a Databricks instance` mean? Are you running a notebook? A job??? There is no such thing as "Databricks instance". There are clusters/jobs/...

Comment: @Kashyap You're right, my bad for the poor phrasing. I edited the wording in the question

Comment: @kindall It is indeed displayed in a browser. Your suggestion resolved my issue. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Wooly No need, I've got enough reputation. Upvoted your answer, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character `<` in the output is being interpreted as the beginning of an HTML tag. By applying `replace("<","&lt;")` to the f-string, this can be avoided. The full code then becomes:

```
num = 5
assert isinstance(num,str), f"type of {num} is {type(num)}".replace("<", "&lt;")
```

Comment: A clear bug in Databricks. Raise it with their support.

Comment: Great catch on this.